# What are the advantages of configuration based routing over component based routing with react router 6.4+

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Prior to react-router 6.4, I was happily declaring my routes using the `<Routes>` and `<Route>` components.
Wherever I wanted some route-dependent rendering, I could use these 2 components.
I was able to nest routes, again by using the `<Routes>` and `<Route>` components in a nested component. I was also able to even use multiple `Routes` containers next to each other in 1 component.

I like this a lot because it keeps things small, nested routes can be handled in the nested component and don't need to bloat the root component. But most of all I like it because seeing the routes in your code where they actually will be rendered makes the code very readable and easy to visualize for me.

Now with react-router 6.4 it seems like they are moving more to a configuration based style of routing, where you define all routes on a root level. In some interviews it's clear that the maintainers are proud that they can now define nested routes on a root level. https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/overview#nested-routes
With that approach, you need to use the `<Outlet/>` component in spots where you want to render the nested route. When reading the code you to cross reference those `Outlet` locations with the configuration on the root level to figure out what is rendered where, which makes things much harder to visualize mentally.

So here's my question: what are the advantages of using such a configuration approach. Any guesses to why the maintainers are taking this road?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Clarifications

- First, since the introduction of `react-router@6` you could use a routes configuration via the `useRoutes` hook ***or*** just use the RRD components and define the JSX for them. This is the "configuration based" vs "component based" routing you describe. It's nothing new in RRDv6.4.

  Configuration Example:

  ```
  import { useRoutes } from 'react-router-dom';

  const routes = [
    {
      element: <Layout />,
      children: [
        {
          path: "/foobar",
          element: <FooBar />
        },
        {
          path: "/foo",
          element: <Foo />
        },
        {
          path: "/bar",
          element: <Bar />
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      path: "/",
      element: <Home />
    },
  ];

  const App = () => {
    const appRoutes = useRoutes(routes);
    return appRoutes;
  };
  ```

  Component Example:

  ```
  import { Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

  const App = () => (
    <Routes>
      <Route element={<Layout />}>
        <Route path="/foobar" element={<Foobar />} />
        <Route path="/foo" element={<Foo />} />
        <Route path="/bar" element={<Bar />} />
      <Route>
      <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
    </Routes>
  );
  ```

  I believe somewhere in the older RRD docs outright stated that the `Routes` component was implemented using the `useRoutes` hook under-the-hood by converting the JSX you pass as children into a routes configuration object.
- Second, what you are describing as "nested routes" are *actually* called descendent routes. Nested routes on the other hand are `Route` components directly rendering other `Route` components that render their content into the `Outlet` of their parent route.

  Descendent routes are good for code/route splitting.

## Question

> So here's my question: what are the advantages of using such a
> configuration approach. Any guesses to why the maintainers are taking
> this road?

What RRDv6.4 introduced was a new Data API which uses new Data Routers. See [Picking a Router](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/routers/picking-a-router). Along with the new Data Routers came an updated [`Route`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/route/route) component with a bunch of new props/functionality to be used within these new Data Routers. Now herein lies the rub. In order for the `Route` components to take advantage of the new Data APIs ([`action`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/route/route#action), [`errorElement`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/route/route#errorelement), [`loader`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/route/route#loader), and [`shouldRevalidate`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/route/should-revalidate) props) they ***necessarily*** need to be defined/configured when creating the Data Router. It doesn't matter if you use a routes "configuration" object with [`createBrowserRouter`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/routers/create-browser-router) or use JSX with both `createBrowserRouter` and the [`createRoutesFromElements`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/utils/create-routes-from-elements) utility, all the routes that need the Data APIs need to be declared here.

The "advantage" is that you can use the new Data APIs with these routes. Of course the library maintainers are going to advertise and highlight their newest products and features.

AFAIK, the Data APIs don't currently work with descendent routes because these can be dynamic and there's not an easy way for a `Route` component to know what descendent `Route` components might be rendered under it in its sub-ReactTree at run-time. This is why nested routes are paramount; it's trivial to setup and maintain the overhead of the Data APIs when you know ahead of time exactly what routes can be rendered and what data they may manage.

Comment: That is a very clear answer, thank you for that

Comment: Fwiw, I had a hard time googling up what "new Data API" meant... the React Router pages weren't real forthcoming either, until I finally dug into [`createBrowserRouter`'s page](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/routers/create-browser-router), which spilled the beans: "_This is the recommended router for all React Router web projects. It uses the [DOM History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History) to update the URL and manage the history stack._" It's that normalized/standardized and relatively new DOM **History** API that's pushing all this forward.

Comment: @ruffin Yeah, sometimes the RRD docs can be a little rough when they introduce new features. The Data APIs were quite hand-wavey when introduced. Probably still are if you are already generally unfamiliar with RRD.