# Configuration based React Router in TypeScript throwing eslint errors

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router

Okay, as I look through the docs for React Router, [I see that the suggestion is](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/routers/picking-a-router#using-v64-data-apis) to use the new routers that support the standard [Data History Web APIs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History), which are relatively new.

I'm in a browser, so I'm going to use [`createBrowserRouter`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/routers/create-browser-router).

There's some sample code there in JavaScript. I need to port this to TypeScript for my project.

```
import * as React from "react";
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import {
  createBrowserRouter,
  RouterProvider,
} from "react-router-dom";

import Root, { rootLoader } from "./routes/root";
import Team, { teamLoader } from "./routes/team";

const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <Root />,
    loader: rootLoader,
    children: [
      {
        path: "team",
        element: <Team />,
        loader: teamLoader,
      },
    ],
  },
]);

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(
  <RouterProvider router={router} />
);
```

When I do, I have errors.

I tried removing most of the stuff I don't think I need, like the loaders, etc.

Here's my first cut:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import { createBrowserRouter, RouterProvider } from 'react-router-dom';
import type { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import AnItem from './components/Shared/AnItem';

const myRouter: BrowserRouter = createBrowserRouter([
    {
        path: '/',
        element: <AnItem />,
    },
]);

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')!).render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <RouterProvider router={myRouter} />
    </React.StrictMode>
);
```

There, I get a number of issues about `any` values, starting with the following line:

`const myRouter: BrowserRouter = createBrowserRouter([`

There are three errors reported just for that line (I'll include them all in a screenshot, below):

- Unsafe assignment of an `any` value.
- 'BrowserRouter' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof BrowserRouter'?
- Unsafe call of an `any` typed value.

[image: errors as displayed in VS Code]

What's wrong there? I've typed `myRouter`. I get that the array is untyped for `createBrowserRouter`, but I thought it could infer.

But let's pull it out and strongly type that array.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import type { RouteObject } from 'react-router';
import type { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { createBrowserRouter, RouterProvider } from 'react-router-dom';
import AnItem from './components/Shared/AnItem';

const routes: RouteObject[] = [
    {
        path: '/',
        element: <AnItem />,
    },
];

const myRouter: BrowserRouter = createBrowserRouter(routes);

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')!).render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <RouterProvider router={myRouter} />
    </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Now it's happy through `routes` but still yells at me for...

`const myRouter: BrowserRouter = createBrowserRouter(routes);`

> Unsafe assignment of an `any` value.

[image: VS Code popover explaining the Unsafe assignment of an any value.]

Where is the `any`? Is it from `createBrowserRouter` somehow? If I mouseover in VS Code, I get "intellisense" (if that's still what it's called), so I think my types, etc, are all mapping correctly:

```
(alias) createBrowserRouter(routes: RouteObject[], opts?: {
    basename?: string | undefined;
    hydrationData?: Partial<Pick<RouterState, "loaderData" | "actionData" | "errors">> | undefined;
    window?: Window | undefined;
} | undefined): Router
import createBrowserRouter
```

That says pretty clearly it returns a `Router`.

It looks like it can't figure out what `BrowserRouter` is from that `type BrowserRouter = /*unresolved*/ any`. But when I mouseover the import, I get:

```
(alias) function BrowserRouter({ basename, children, window, }: BrowserRouterProps): JSX.Element
import BrowserRouter
A <Router> for use in web browsers. Provides the cleanest URLs.

'BrowserRouter' is declared but its value is never read.ts(6133)
```

So that seems in context too, though the "its value is never read" is surprising.

Now I did try to type `myRouter` as a `Router`, but I get yelled at that I should use a more specific type of router:

> Note: You usually won't render a directly [sic]. Instead, you'll render a router that is more specific to your environment such as a in web browsers or a for server rendering.

So I'm using `BrowserRouter`. But its error is:

> 'BrowserRouter' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof BrowserRouter'?

I'm pretty sure I don't mean `typeof`; I'm defining a variable as a specifc type.

What am I missing here? I'm having a hard time googling up an example that both uses configuration instead of components for routing (and [I think configuration is what I want](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74886386/1028230) as the new Data History API routers require it) and is in TypeScript.

Looks like Drew's on to something. Here are my dependencies from package.json:

```
    "dependencies": {
        "bootstrap": "^5.2.3",
        "react": "^18.2.0",
        "react-bootstrap": "^2.7.0",
        "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
        "react-router": "^6.7.0",
        "react-router-dom": "^6.7.0"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@types/react": "^18.0.26",
        "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.9",
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.48.2",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.48.2",
        "@vitejs/plugin-react-swc": "^3.0.0",
        "eslint": "^8.32.0",
        "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.6.0",
        "eslint-config-xo": "^0.43.1",
        "eslint-config-xo-typescript": "^0.55.1",
        "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.32.1",
        "opener": "^1.5.2",
        "typescript": "^4.9.4",
        "vite": "^4.0.0"
    }
```

---

Update: If I disable those rules and take out the typing, things do render as I'd expect.

```
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-assignment */
//...
const routes: RouteObject[] = [
    {
        path: '/',
        element: (
            <div>
                <a href="./test">test</a>
            </div>
        ),
    },
    { path: '/test', element: <div>hello</div> },
];

// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-call
const myRouter = createBrowserRouter(routes);

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')!).render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <RouterProvider router={myRouter} />
    </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Comment: What are, or were, the initial errors you faced? Have you just recently upgraded from RRD v5 to v6? Can you [edit] the post to provide the error(s)? Do you mind also sharing your package.json file so we can inspect the dependencies?

Comment: @DrewReese Yep, I've edited and added them. Apologies; they're mentioned later, but out of context. This is a brand new, greenfield codebase for the purposes of this question.

Comment: I don't believe you should need to type the data router, but if you did, the [`creacteBrowserRouter` return type is `RemixRouter`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/routers/create-browser-router#type-declaration). Note that this isn't the same as the exported `BrowserRouter` component.

Comment: @DrewReese You must be on to something asking about versioning, as VS Code doesn't find `RemixRouter` when I try to use it. I'll add some package.json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`react-router@6` and `react-router-dom@6` are completely written in Typescript, so there is no need to import external typings. The v5 typings are likely messing with your build step.

You should uninstall `@types/react-router` and `@types/react-router-dom`.

```
npm uninstall --save @types/react-router
npm uninstall --save @types/react-router-dom
```

From here I don't believe you'll need to explicitly type the data router. The return type from `createBrowserRouter` is `RemixRouter`, not `BrowserRouter`.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import { createBrowserRouter, RouterProvider } from 'react-router-dom';
import AnItem from './components/Shared/AnItem';

const myRouter = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: '/',
    element: <AnItem />,
  },
]);

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')!)
  .render(
    <React.StrictMode>
      <RouterProvider router={myRouter} />
    </React.StrictMode>
  );
```

Comment: This is certainly better, but I'm still getting that last ``Unsafe assignment of an `any` value.`` for `<RouterProvider router={myRouter} />`. I've tried `Router`, `RemixRouter`, and `BrowserRouter` for `XXX` in `const myRouter: XXX`, and either get it can't be found to import (RemixRouter & BrowserRouter) or "_'Router' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof Router'?_" for `Router` imported as a type.

Comment: Yep, as your edit suggests, taking the type out works. Phew. Thank you. Was banging my head a little there.

Comment: @ruffin Typescript has really improved the past couple years, and working with TS has gotten better since more libraries use TS... we no longer need to "type everything, type everywhere".